# Very large data for Xcode iOS unit tests

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, continuous-integration, video-processing

### Summary

How do I get realistic automated unit tests for multiple large data sets for an iOS application? The more realistic the test, the harder it is to do; and using a continuous-integration server (the only practical way to conduct tests) compounds the problem.

But people do it. How?

I make a number of flat assertions. Any may be incorrect. Correcting them will go a long way toward answering my question.

---

### Project

This is an iOS 9 application that analyzes large video files (full-resolution, maximum frame rate, 10 seconds typical) taken on an iOS device. (Part of the analysis will go through [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/), if that matters.)

The client has given us a proof-of-concept (Python on the desktop) and hundreds of sample files. Call it 8 GB total.

We’d like to unit-test our code against as many of these as possible. My problem is, how do we perform automated unit tests against large data sets for an iOS target?

---

### Alternatives

The better the test, the harder it is to perform:

We’ll start with an **OS X application** to check correctness and *relative* speed. It’s easy to point the tool at any number of files. However, `x86_64` has a different ABI, OS X a different API, and iOS has resource constraints the Mac won’t reproduce.

This affects both correctness and performance measures: You could go on wild goose chases for optimizations that work on the desktop but not the device. We will eventually have to use the Accelerate framework, which can’t possibly perform the same on the two platforms.

---

After porting to iOS, we can **use the iOS Simulator**, which even uses `i386` (and therefore a 32-bit word) for older targets. (I explode with delight to discover that the precision of `CGFloat` varies between platforms.) Still the problems of ABI, performance, and constraints, compounded by the fact that the Simulator’s “iOS” API often calls through to the *approximate* equivalents in OS X.

Additionally, I don’t believe the simulated device can break the sandbox to read files outside the device’s tree. We must (am I right?) copy the test data into the storage of each simulated device, at paths that will differ for each developer and are not guaranteed to be stable across versions of Xcode. If that were solved, even a big machine would still have problems with *n* × *m* GB.

(We could link all the “stored” files to a common copy. The reliability and stability issues delight me even more.)

---

Eventually we have to **test on a device**, because we need unpaged memory, storage that is a small multiple of the file size, on a throttled ARM processor that changes significantly every year. Which means pushing video files through the tether, possibly seriatim. It’s unrealistic to challenge the device with hundreds (or dozens) of files, but an adequate test suite might demand 8 — enough to be cumbersome.

I’m not sanguine about there being a straightforward way to load and unload a series of files into a tethered device. I guess we might have separate test targets, each with two or three files stashed into the application data package for the **Test** scheme of each. I’d rather not if there’s a cleaner way.

---

### Integration

It gets worse: Testing will be a long, demanding process, multiplied by each targeted device. It is not realistic to ask any of our developers to host the tests (everybody is BYOD and occasionally off-site, let’s not argue about it). Nor is it realistic to commit the test files to a shared repository. (GitHub flatly refuses.) That’s true no matter how you perform the tests.

This points to builds and tests on a continuous-integration server. We wouldn’t have to bear the tedium, but the practical problems of keeping a library of test data and loading it into the sandbox of the device (simulated or practical) don’t go away.

---

### Question

I *know* this is a solved problem. Large-file projects for mobile devices exist. The developers test them.

How is it done?

Comment: Would love to know this as well. We're working on an app that does a lot of data processing so testing with real data (it's several gigabytes) would provide more accurate test results. I've tried bundling it as supporting files but then it's very slow to run every time.

Answer (score 0):

Run into this today. Luckily we are now living in post iOS 11 era and have file providers so we only need to upload the files manually once to the testing device, its then just a good file name organizing.